# What's the effect of having a neighbor tap on your house?

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

When a neighbor visits your Springfield and taps on your houses, the neighbor will earn $16 and 2XP per house.

The immediate effect you can observe is that you will see the interlocked hands symbol over your house and when you tap it, you'll see the name of the neighbor appear.

[image]

But what other, if any, effects are there for you? From what I can observe, the tapped houses don't pay out more money. So, is there any benefit for you?

Answer (score 4):

I have noticed that if a neighbour taps one of my properties that earn money over time, the amount of time it takes to generate the next pay out can be reduced.

It's more noticeable when they tap a property that takes 8 - 24 hours.

When I tap on the neighbour icon and get the money on the property, then tap to check "time remaining", I find the "time remaining" can be much less, (*i.e.* instead of 24 hours remaining, it says only 17 hours remaining).

I've always suspected it's based on when they tapped it, which is when the clock resets on that property. But, it's hard to confirm since my friends usually tap on the houses which have much shorter time remaining, so the effect does not appear.

Comment: I actually suspect the same. I have a large collection of white houses, which I usually activate in regular intervals. Every once in a while, some of them will be ready to pay out hours before the rest of them.